# Point hostname to different IP in Windows DNS Server

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, thin-client

Because HP won't change the folder structure on their FTP server's we can't update our Thin Clients. I experimented with recreating the right folder structure and then pointing ftp.hp.com to our internal FTP server in the HOSTS file on the Thinclient. This did the trick.

I need to update some 50 thinclients so changing the hosts file on each one by hand is a pain. I was wondering if and how I can configure our Windows DNS Server to trick the thinclients into thinking ftp.hp.com is for ex. 10.10.10.50...

Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to create a zone (primary or AD integrated) for *ftp.hp.com*.  Then create a parent host record (A with no name) that points at 10.10.10.50.

This should allow the server to respond to requests for ftp.hp.com without causing problems for the rest of the hp.com domain (except sub-domains of ftp.hp.com).

Comment: Ok cheers. I tried that but i must have done something wrong because it did not work. I'll try again :-)

Comment: Make sure the zone is on all DNS servers that the clients use too.

Answer (score 0):

Create a zone called hp.com on your DNS server and add record ftp.hp.com pointing to 10.10.10.50 IP.